# What html/jquery/ any other element can i use to create a 'box' like that of a tooltip window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-frontend

I'm new to front end development and I have a requirement in my web app where **if a user hovers over an image, a 'box' opens nearby and displays a pie chart.**

I could get the hover function to work but I'm not sure how to go ahead with the box feature. Any ideas as to what html element or specific library i could use to accomplish this?

```
$('#vmtable tbody td#storage').hover(

    function () {
        // i tried opening a div on hover but i know this is not what is required. 
        // It just expands my parent element.
        $(this.childNodes[3]).css("display", "block"); 
        var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    }, 

    function () {
        $(this.childNodes[3]).css("display", "none");
        var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    }

);
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Did you hear about CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [jQuery Tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content). I think that's what you are looking for.

[image]

> *[API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/)*

Comment: can i display a piechart in a tooltip ?

Comment: @NeuralLynx Sure. You can display whatever you like. Just change the `content` block.

Comment: @NeuralLynx If you specify what piechart we are talking about, i may try to provide an example.

Comment: this is exactly what i need. Could you please share the approach for displaying google pie chart in the tooltip

Answer (score 1):

> Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#test" ).hover(function() {
           $('.modal').modal({
        show: true
    });
  });  
});
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4556/

Answer (score 0):

I used the `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events combined with setting the source in jQuery.

```js
$("#images img").on("mouseover", function () {
  $("#bigger").attr("src",$(this).attr("src"));
}).on("mouseleave", function () {
  $("#bigger").attr("src","");
});
```

```css
#images img {
  max-width: 50px;
  height:40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#bigger {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="images">
  <img src="http://neil.computer/stack/bg.jpg" />
  <img src="http://neil.computer/stack/bg2.jpg" />
  <img src="http://neil.computer/stack/bg3.jpg" />
</div>

<img id="bigger" />
```

Comment: this is a good solution but i require a box like a small window, not a tab.

Comment: Does any of the other answer satisfy you? If not I'll write up an example on how to do that.

Comment: No, nothing seems to tailor what i require. Yes, please do provide example

Comment: I updated my answer, if you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot.  If you want the images to stay up, simply remove the `mouseleave` event.